# CKEditor is stripping <figure> and <figcaption> tags

Tags: ckeditor, figure

I know that I can add exceptions in CKEditor config file to allow certain HTML tags, but I was hoping there might be an easier way to do this

Basically, I just need a simple way to caption images with text. Any idea how I can replicate the functionality of `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` with something that CKEditor won't strip?

Comment: I am not sure which CKEditor version you are using, but CKEditor probably strips your `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` tags because the default automatic [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) mode is on and these elements are not supported by any of the features (plugins etc.) that your editor build has. Most importantly, however, check out the [Enhanced Image](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/captionedimage.html) plugin which allows for adding captioned images without any hacking :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, it turns out you can mostly replicate the functionality using just `<div>`s and some inline styling. Below is formatted for the left side, but you could change `float` to `right` and change `margin-right` to `margin-left` to achieve the same effect.

```
<div style="float:left;margin-right:15px;margin-bottom:5px;font-style:italic">
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" style="height:300px; width:300px" />
    <div style="max-width:300px">This is a caption</div>
</div>
```

```html
<div style="float:left;margin-right:15px;margin-bottom:5px;font-style:italic"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" style="height:300px; width:300px" /><div style="max-width:300px">This is a caption</div></div>
<p>Collaboratively administrate empowered markets via plug-and-play networks. Dynamically procrastinate B2C users after installed base benefits. Dramatically visualize customer directed convergence without revolutionary ROI.</p><p>Efficiently unleash cross-media information without cross-media value. Quickly maximize timely deliverables for real-time schemas. Dramatically maintain clicks-and-mortar solutions without functional solutions.</p><p>Completely synergize resource taxing relationships via premier niche markets. Professionally cultivate one-to-one customer service with robust ideas. Dynamically innovate resource-leveling customer service for state of the art customer service.</p><p>Objectively innovate empowered manufactured products whereas parallel platforms. Holisticly predominate extensible testing procedures for reliable supply chains. Dramatically engage top-line web services vis-a-vis cutting-edge deliverables.</p><p>Proactively envisioned multimedia based expertise and cross-media growth strategies. Seamlessly visualize quality intellectual capital without superior collaboration and idea-sharing. Holistically pontificate installed base portals after maintainable products.</p><p>Phosfluorescently engage worldwide methodologies with web-enabled technology. Interactively coordinate proactive e-commerce via process-centric "outside the box" thinking. Completely pursue scalable customer service through sustainable potentialities.</p><p>Collaboratively administrate turnkey channels whereas virtual e-tailers. Objectively seize scalable metrics whereas proactive e-services. Seamlessly empower fully researched growth strategies and interoperable internal or "organic" sources.</p><p>Credibly innovate granular internal or "organic" sources whereas high standards in web-readiness. Energistically scale future-proof core competencies vis-a-vis impactful experiences. Dramatically synthesize integrated schemas with optimal networks.</p>
```

Edit: Below is a link I just found which utilizes CSS float and achieves a similar effect, and the text does wrap doing it in this manner.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float3

Comment: But then you loose the accessibility that comes with semantic HTML5 markup.  Why do it all with div's when that isn't what they are there for?